# Godaddy: domain path doesn't work

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, domain-forwarding

I've read quite a few questions here and I got a better idea about my issue:

With forward + masking in godaddy you only see your domain and don't see the path. This is what I initially did. My issue was that

1) You don't see the path

2) You links of the type mydomain.com/path/to/content don't work.

Currently I have this setup:
Redirect: 301 (Permanent)
Type: Forward only

And it is getthing there. Currently my issues above are fixed, BUT when I click on the link I see the ip of my vps, **not** the domain name. What settings must I set in godaddy's admin panel to reslove this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that from the DNS settings you need to create a new host record.

Comment: "a new host record" - what's that?